# How to show image uploading counter on progress bar in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am want to show image counter on the progress bar dialog. I am using volley library in this, I using a progress bar to show the image uploading status. I am able to get the total number of images. But the current image counter image uploading is not showing. Like if there are 10 image to upload initially it should show on 0/10, first image upload 1/10, on second upload 2/10, on third image upload 3/10...10/10. How I can do this in android is there any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

we have to override  `onPostExecute` `doInBackground` `onPreExecute` method.

doInBackground method will count to number of images that have been uploaded and that count variable can be displayed using ProgressBar.